# Is there an adjectival form for "story" or a similar word?

Tags: adjectives

I'm looking for an adjective that alludes to something having a rich story or meaningful tale. The closest word I can think of is "plotful," but it doesn't completely satisfy the context.

Comment: I've seen E. M. Forster use the descriptor "well-plotted" to describe novels with rich plot.

Comment: Well, there's always "storied".

Comment: Can you provide a sentence where the word you want is marked 'X'?

Comment: I wasn't actually thinking of the word in a particular sentence, but rather to describe a category. I am sorting a list of songs by attributes, and I knew I wanted a category for songs that "told a story," but I couldn't think of the right adjective. I chose narrative below because it fits this use, however—based on the way I asked the question—I think "well-plotted," "storied," etc., are also fitting for such a word.

Comment: @penguinick77 *Storied* is not really the adjectival of *story*. Its meaning, according to the OED is *fabled*, or *legendary*. If you google its synonyms you get words like *famous*, *illustrious*, *acclaimed*, *celebrated*.  You wouldn't say *The author provides a storied account of Hoggard's life*.  That wouldn't make sense. One would use *narrative* for that purpose. You might say *His has been a storied life*, meaning rich in experience, influence and events.

Comment: 'Narrative' is the right adjective for lyrics. 'Plot' and 'story' mean distinctly different things: a plot is not a story, although it may be part of a story.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

narrative

I think it is right to the point. The reason is that it is very common to say a narrative painting (or other fine arts) when you mean the work that tells a lot.

This is more or less the same trough various dictionaries:

[narrative](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/narrative)

adjective

4. consisting of or being a narrative: a narrative poem.
5. of or relating to narration, or the telling of a story: My English teacher's narrative skill makes characters seem to come to life.
6. Fine Arts. representing stories or events pictorially or sculpturally: narrative painting.

Example:

"I was immediately attracted and immediately fascinated by something that was so narrative."

Comment: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/narrative
 **narrative**  
(adjective)   
"In the form of or concerned with narration."

Comment: Hmm ... but it doesn't make clear whether good or bad.

Comment: You have to use it in the right context. That is the way of getting shades of the meaning. But the potential is definitely there.

Comment: Not disagreeing, but would you please supply a more or less authoritative external reference or example of this use to support the claim? Googling "narrative lyrics" would provide you with some. Thanks, I upticked your answer because it is right, but support for your claim beyond just your say-so is highly desirable in the context of EL&U.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously "plotful" works and is a word.  The adjective "well-plotted" would mean, "an extensively devised or constructed the plot of (a play, novel, etc.)."

If these don't fit the bill, you might look at the adjective "storied."  However, that would only fit if it were particularly epic, intricately covering a great deal of history or was at least historical fiction.

While it is a noun, a rich story with a complex plot is idiomatically called a "yarn."  Telling such a story is "twisting a yarn."  You can then employ colorful modifiers like, "He twisted a tangled yarn," and "Twisting an unraveling yarn, the author..."  To describe a plot, you might say, "The plot was a tightly twisted yarn about..."